# Unknown scope provider $scope

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

I am trying to inject $scope but it's not working. This is my code:

```js
var appCtrl = app.controller(
    'AppCtrl', 
    function ($scope, $resource, $location, $route, sharedProperties) {}
);

appCtrl.prepData = function (
    $q, $scope, $resource, $location, $route, sharedProperties) {}
```

I am trying to define a function after getting the appCtrl variable. But $scope wouldn't work there. Any idea how to resolve this issue?

Comment: What exactly you want to do? create a function in controller? To do this you need to create the funcrion inside the controller,,  which already have the $scope.

Comment: @Deividi: Yes, I know but I want to be able to create function outside controller and inject $scope there. Any way to do that?

Comment: Yes, but you need to declare the controller as a module and use the angular.bootstrap() function. Take a look at http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/bootstrap . But I didn't know if you can declare a new function in this case. Is any reason to not declare inside the controller or something like that?